# Google Analytics API - Average Session time doesn't fit with Analytics Dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I am using the Google Analytics API and want to know the average session duration of a spezific content site.

To get the metrics I am using this PHP Code:

```
$result = $analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:XXXXXXX',
            '2012-01-01',
            date("Y-m-d"),
            'ga:visits',
            array(
                'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==MY_URL',
                'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
                'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews,ga:sessions,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:bounces',
                'sort' => '-ga:uniquePageviews',
                'max-results' => '25'
            )
        );
```

I get the following result:

```
[0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => MY_URL
                    [1] => 8966
                    [2] => 7434
                    [3] => 7434
                    [4] => 17.15496368038741
                    [5] => 6245
                )
```

Numbers 0-3 and 5 are exactly the same like Google Analytics Dashboard numbers (when I am logged in with my browser in google analytics)

But **average duration time on site** doesn't fit. API shows me 17.15 seconds and Google Analytics dashboard shows me 1 minute and 23 seconds.

Are these the same metrics? I want to have the "average duration time on site" (like standard Analytics Dashboard shows me).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no average duration time on site dimension. There is Avg. Time on Page and Avg. Session Duration. The confusion might be that you are looking at Time on Page in your dashboard, rather then session duration.

You might want to try ga:avgTimeOnPage instead of ga:avgSessionDuration.

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I want to have. Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: Another thing: Do you know why ga:avgTimeOnPage and ga:avgSessionDuration having such a difference? For example: now I have 5 seconds (ga:avgSessionDuration) against 87 seconds (ga:avgTimeOnPage). What's the different meaning?

Comment: My assumption without understanding your website data, would be that this page might be a high bounce page.    1) Time on page is the time between page load, and the next page loading. Time on page does not capture users who bounce/exit as the value is never populated.   2) Session Duration is the time taken from the first interaction to the last interaction. This metric is populated with 0 initially and incrementally increases with every hit. This metric, in contrast to Time on Page, will be 0 if the user bounces.